# Apply Slide transition to the children of a ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to iterate over a LinearLayout's children and apply Slide transitions so that they appear one after the other in a coordinated manner. First, views are visible. Then I call `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` and apply `gone` or `invisible` visibilities on the children. The view hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bruce Lee"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"
            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jason Statham"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jean-Claude Van Damme"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arnold Schwarzenegger"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sylvester Stallone"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scot Atkins"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bruce Lee"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"

            />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When applying `gone`, the children disappear abruptly. With, `invisible`, they disappear in a venticular chaotic manner.
My activity code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mButton;
    ViewGroup mContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContainer = findViewById(R.id.container);
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.start);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick: child count: " + mContainer.getChildCount());
                for(int i = 0; i < mContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick: transitioning child " + mContainer.getChildAt(i).toString());
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container), new Slide().setDuration(1000));
                    (mContainer.getChildAt(i)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `layout_height` in your `LinearLayout` to `"match_parent"`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

**UPDATE:** I can't believe you want to hide your items forever, moreover I think you don't want the items to go to the bottom instead of the right side of screen. Let me suggest you one more fix for your Java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = mContainer.getChildAt(i);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mContainer, new Slide(Gravity.END).setDuration(1000));
    child.setVisibility(child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Anyway, now you have more options to play with.

**UPDATE2**: Post transition as delayed Runnables.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  for(int i = 0; i < mContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final View child = mContainer.getChildAt(i);
    final Transition slide = new Slide(Gravity.END).setDuration(1000);
    mContainer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mContainer, slide);
        child.setVisibility(child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }, 1000 * i);
  }
}
```

[image: Smooth version] 
[image: Step by step version]

Comment: How do you reverse the transition in the gif?

Comment: It's in suggested Java code.
`child.setVisibility(child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);`
We check if a child is visible, if yes we make it gone, if it's gone, we make it visible.

Comment: How can I make items go away or appear one at a time rather than with some delay? Let's say item one goes out of the screen, then the second starts moving and goes out of the screen from the edge, and so on.

Comment: There are various ways. The first thing comes in mind -- use `Transition.TransitionListener` for your Slide transition.

Or you can implement much more easier but not wonderful solution, which I should add in my answer.

Comment: Nice! Could you explain why you are multiplying 1000*i each iteration?

Comment: "1000" is the duration of transition animation in milliseconds from your original code. If you want to run the next animation right after the previous, your delay have to be proportional to View index multiplied by duration of the animation. In that case, first View is animated after 1000 * 0 == 0 milliseconds, second after 1000 * 1 == 1000 milliseconds, third after 1000 * 2 == 2000 milliseconds, etc. The best practice here is to declare `private static final int SLIDE_DURATION = 1000;` and use in `.setDuration(SLIDE_DURATION)` and `SLIDE_DURATION * i` both.